# Button navigation not working properly in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am beginner for the React-JS. In here I try to click on the button and navigate to the another page. But navigation is not working properly. I call the on click function in to the button correctly. Can you guys check my code and solve my problem? "**Voir toutes les notifications**" is the button name.

```
import React from 'react'
import Footer from '../../components/Footer/index.js';
import Header from "../../components/Header/index.js"
import Carnetdenote from "../../public/img/Carnetdenote.svg"
import Settings from "../../public/img/AdminSettings.svg"
import Producteurs from "../../public/img/Producteurs.svg"




class consultantdashboard extends React.Component {

    onClick = () => this.props.history.push("/consultantnotification_2.6");

    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                <Header></Header>
                <div>

                    <div>
                        <main>
                            <div className="headerBecground">


                               

                                <div >

                                    <div className="desktophidden">
                                        <div className="producteure-dashboard-table-box">

                                            <h4 className="headerColor">Notifications</h4>

                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <table class="table">

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;2021-03-29<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Victor Morin</td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg>
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;2021-03-29<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Un nouveau commentaire à été ajouté<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Victor Morin</td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2021-03-29<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Victor Morin</td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary primaryTop" onClick={this.onClick}>Voir toutes les notificationsx</button></tr>



                                                </table>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <br></br>


                                <div class=" mobilehidden">

                                    <div class="container-fluid" >

                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div className="producteure-dashboard-table-box">

                                                <h4 className="headerColor">Notifications</h4>



                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table class="table " width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th></th>
                                                                <th>Date</th>
                                                                <th>Activité</th>
                                                                <th>Auteur</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg></td>
                                                            <td>2021-03-29</td>
                                                            <td>Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté</td>
                                                            <td>Victor Morin</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512" ><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg></td>
                                                            <td>2021-03-29</td>
                                                            <td>Un nouveau commentaire à été ajouté</td>
                                                            <td>Victor Morin</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td>2021-03-29</td>
                                                            <td>Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté</td>
                                                            <td>Victor Morin</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary primaryTop">Voir toutes les notificationsx</button></td>
                                                        </tr>



                                                    </table>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>




                                <div className="producteure-dashboard-box">

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">

                                            <div id="grid" class="row">

                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="producteure-dashboard-grid-item">
                                                            <img src={Producteurs} class="img-responsive" alt="workimg" />
                                                            <p>Producteurs</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="producteure-dashboard-grid-item">
                                                            <img src={Carnetdenote} class="img-responsive" alt="workimg" />
                                                            <p>Carnet de note</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="producteure-dashboard-grid-item">
                                                            <img src={Settings} class="img-responsive" alt="workimg" />
                                                            <p>Settings</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>











                            </div>



                        </main>

                        <Footer></Footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default consultantdashboard
```

Comment: Try wrapping the onClick of the button in ES6 arrow function - i.e, () => this.onClick()

Comment: `navigation is not working properly`. Can you show detail error or behavior?

Comment: hey @Incorrect syntax near can you given some example for that

Comment: Yeah, there is provided a working solution for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246933/onclick-not-firing-in-react

Comment: @Incorrect syntax near the problem is I want to navigate with another page how can I do it. Can you change my code and given some answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to another page by using the `<Redirect to="{your path}" />` of react-router-dom. You might not getting history in the props, so you are not able to redirect.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Footer from '../../components/Footer/index.js';
import Header from "../../components/Header/index.js"
import Carnetdenote from "../../public/img/Carnetdenote.svg"
import Settings from "../../public/img/AdminSettings.svg"
import Producteurs from "../../public/img/Producteurs.svg"

class consultantdashboard extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           redirect: null
       };
   }

  onClick = () => this.setState({ redirect: "/consultantnotification_2.6" });

  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
        return <Redirect to={this.state.redirect} />
    }

    return (

        <div>
            <Header></Header>
            <div>

                <div>
                    <main>
                        <div className="headerBecground">


                           

                            <div >

                                <div className="desktophidden">
                                    <div className="producteure-dashboard-table-box">

                                        <h4 className="headerColor">Notifications</h4>

                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table">

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;2021-03-29<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Victor Morin</td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;2021-03-29<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Un nouveau commentaire à été ajouté<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Victor Morin</td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2021-03-29<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Victor Morin</td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary primaryTop" onClick={this.onClick}>Voir toutes les notificationsx</button></tr>



                                            </table>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <br></br>


                            <div class=" mobilehidden">

                                <div class="container-fluid" >

                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div className="producteure-dashboard-table-box">

                                            <h4 className="headerColor">Notifications</h4>



                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                <table class="table " width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th>Date</th>
                                                            <th>Activité</th>
                                                            <th>Auteur</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg></td>
                                                        <td>2021-03-29</td>
                                                        <td>Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté</td>
                                                        <td>Victor Morin</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-circle fa-w-16 fontColorRed" viewBox="0 0 512 512" ><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8z"></path></svg></td>
                                                        <td>2021-03-29</td>
                                                        <td>Un nouveau commentaire à été ajouté</td>
                                                        <td>Victor Morin</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td>2021-03-29</td>
                                                        <td>Une nouvelle photo à été ajouté</td>
                                                        <td>Victor Morin</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary primaryTop">Voir toutes les notificationsx</button></td>
                                                    </tr>



                                                </table>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>




                            <div className="producteure-dashboard-box">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">

                                        <div id="grid" class="row">

                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="producteure-dashboard-grid-item">
                                                        <img src={Producteurs} class="img-responsive" alt="workimg" />
                                                        <p>Producteurs</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="producteure-dashboard-grid-item">
                                                        <img src={Carnetdenote} class="img-responsive" alt="workimg" />
                                                        <p>Carnet de note</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-6">
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="producteure-dashboard-grid-item">
                                                        <img src={Settings} class="img-responsive" alt="workimg" />
                                                        <p>Settings</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>











                        </div>



                    </main>

                    <Footer></Footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default consultantdashboard
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. But the navigation is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> The simplest way is to wrap your component using the withRouter high order component that will add history props to your component.

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
...

class consultantdashboard extends React.Component {
    onClick = () => this.props.history.push("/consultantnotification_2.6");
    render (
        ...
    );
}

export default withRouter(consultantdashboard);
```